# How to enable HTTPS for standalone Wiremock

Tags: https, wiremock

**Overview:**

I used wiremock standalone 2.1.11 and did the following to enable HTTPS URL for my request but to no avail:

- Studying the doc http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/
- Adding --https-port but nothing happened
- Adding keystore but again no progress

The command for running the wiremock is as follows:

```
java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.1.11.jar --port 8920 --https-port 8921 --https-keystore /home/wiremock/keystore/clientkeystore --verbose
```

**Note:** 
I can connect via http port correctly

---

Now I would be grateful if anyone could help me find solution for HTTPS connection.

Comment: Is your keystore password different from "password"? (The documentation  explicitly states "The keystore must have a password of “password”.")

Comment: No I created the keystore base on the wiremock https doc and used "password" as my keystore pass

Answer (score 8):

1. Generate java key store for wiremock

   ```
    keytool -genkey -alias wiremock -keyalg RSA -keysize 1024 \
    -validity 365 -keypass password -keystore identity.jks -storepass password
   ```

   Important --- Follow the prompts to specify the certificate details:

   - First and last name: this is not your name, it is the Common Name (CN), for example 'confluence.example.com'. The CN must match the fully qualified hostname of the server running Confluence, or Tomcat won't be able to use the certificate for SSL.
   - Organizational unit: this is the team or department requesting the certificate, for example 'marketing'.
   - Organization: this is your company name, for example 'SeeSpaceEZ'.
     City, State / province, country code: this is where you're located, for example Sydney, NSW, AU.
2. Create the self-signed certification

   ```
   openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt -config localhost.conf
   ```
3. Import certification into keystore

   ```
    keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mock -file localhost.crt -keystore identity.jks
   ```
4. Start wiremock with the new keystore and HTTPS enabled

   ```
    java -jar wiremock-1.54-standalone.jar --https-port 8443 --https-keystore 
    ./identity.jks
   ```

Resources:

The answer is from 
https://gist.github.com/mobmad/433ba54e9cb97d6d7771#1-generate-self-signed-certificate

Comment: what do you mean by the first bullet...  what does it have to do with confluence? why would you want to make a certificate for it? I thought we need a CA for the wiremock to create its own certificates, not some specific certificate?

Comment: for https, you need to make a CA(any your own local CA)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue where I wanted to mock one https ajax call to third party which is invoked during the page load.
Our original wiremock setup was done on http and hence we were getting the error

```
 was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
```

To fix that I simply need to enable the Wiremock server to listen on Secure port (Please see the bold part of the code). Please see below the UtilityClass which starts stop the WireMock Server before each tests.

```
public class WireMockHook {
    public static final int WIREMOCK_PORT_NUMBER = 8089;
    public static final int WIREMOCK_SECURE_PORT_NUMBER = 8043;
    public static final String WIREMOCK_HOST = "localhost";
    private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    @Before(order = 0)
    public void startWireMock() {
        wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().httpsPort(WIREMOCK_SECURE_PORT_NUMBER).port(WIREMOCK_PORT_NUMBER));
        wireMockServer.start();
        configureFor(WIREMOCK_HOST, WIREMOCK_PORT_NUMBER);
    }

    @After(order = 0)
    public void stopWireMock() {
        wireMockServer.stop();
    }
}
```